# Changing an element to uppercase using javascript

Tags: javascript, uppercase, appendchild

I am having a major problem finding out the correct rule to follow when I am trying to change my input text from textbox to uppercase. What I have is a heading and textarea. When the uppercase is checked the heading should get the uppercase attribute. In the code ther is something about invert, don't pay attention to that for that is a function I can probably work out as soon as I get how we change to uppercase.

The code here is only a part of the whole javascript file:

```
function addText(heading, text, invert, uppercase) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newh2 = document.createElement("h2");
  var texth2 = document.createTextNode(heading);
  newh2.appendChild(texth2);
  var newp = document.createElement("p");
  var textp = document.createTextNode(text);
  newp.appendChild(textp);

  if(uppercase.checked) {
    var newh2 = heading.toUpperCase();
    newdiv.appendChild(newh2);
  }else {
    newdiv.appendChild(newh2);
  }

  if (invert.checked) {
    var newerp;
    newdiv.appendChild(newerp);
    alert("invert checked");
  }else {
    newdiv.appendChild(newp);
  }

textContainer.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Comment: `var newh2.value =` make no sense.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything with the text values and you just want them to display uppercase then this is probably overkill - you can do it very easily with css.

Comment: sorry, that was no supposed to be there...will fix it...thanks man!

Comment: that's the ting Archer....I am not allowed too

Comment: Is `textContainer` defined somewhere else?  You are using `textContainer.appendChild` but I don't see where `textContainer` is defined.

Comment: Can you explain why you are not allowed to?  This is either homework or a ridiculously stupid requirement.  If the end result is uppercase being displayed then CSS is the correct way to achieve it.

Comment: yeah nurdyguy, textContainer is defined somwhere else

Comment: Archer it is a homework assignment

Comment: `newdiv.appendChild(newerp);` ... `newerp` doesn't contain anything, or is that a typo?

Comment: that was a typo, besides it was irrelevent matter!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `newh2.value` to change the content of the `h2`, you can just provide the correct value when creating the text node

```
function addText(heading, text, invert, uppercase) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newh2 = document.createElement("h2");
  var texth2 = document.createTextNode(uppercase.checked ? heading.toUpperCase() : heading); // Like this
  newh2.appendChild(texth2);
  var newp = document.createElement("p");
  var textp = document.createTextNode(text);
  newp.appendChild(textp);

  newdiv.appendChild(newh2);

  if (invert.checked) {
    var newerp;
    newdiv.appendChild(newerp);
    alert("invert checked");
  } else {
    newdiv.appendChild(newp);
  }

  textContainer.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of stuff going on there that's not required.  You just need to create the h2 element, set the text and then add it to the page (or parent element).

This will do what you need...

```js
function addHeading(text) {
  var heading = document.createElement("h2");
  heading.innerText = text.toUpperCase();
  document.body.appendChild(heading);
}

addHeading("This is a heading");
```